# Pointing to User Defined ADTs inside another ADT in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, structure

I have created an abstract data type in C that is based off a structure. Inside this structure, there are pointers to other ADTs that are also based off of structures. I want to know how/if I can properly initialize the pointers on the inside and get rid of my memory access violation errors. The code is below:

```
typedef struct insideADT1_S{
     int someConstant1;
     int someArrray1[500];
} insideADT1_T

typedef struct insideADT2_S{
     int someConstant2;
     int someArray2[500];
} insideADT2_T

typedef struct outsideADT_S{
     insideADT1_T *insidePTR1;
     insideADT2_T *insidePTR2;
} outsideADT_T
```

I create the outside structure and pass it to a function. Inside the function, I try to get one of the inside members, and I crash and get a memory access error. An example is below:

```
outsideADT_T *outsidePTR;
SomeFunction(&outsidePTR);
```

The inside of SomeFunction looks like:

```
void SomeFunction(outsideADT_T *outsidePTR){
    //===Fill Array of Inside ADT===//
    for (i=0; i<500; i++){
        outsidePTR->insidePTR1->someArray1[i] = i;  //OOPS! Memory Access Violation! FAIL!
    }
}
```

However, accessing like this gives me memory access violations. Note that I can solve the problem by using the structure versions, instead of the ADTs, and not defining pointers to those structures. For instance:

```
typedef struct outsideADT_S{
     struct insideADT1_S insideSTC1;
     struct insideADT2_S insideSTC2;
} outsideADT_T

void SomeFunction(outsideADT_T *outsidePTR){
    //===Fill Array of Inside ADT===//
    for (i=0; i<500; i++){
        outsidePTR->insideSTC1.someArray1[i] = i;
    }
}
```

Works fine. Why does the first method fail when the second one doesn't? What am I doing wrong the first time, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Do you initialise those pointers at any point in your code? Can you please post that part?

Comment: No, not explicitly. I was thinking that since I created the outside pointer, the inside ones would get be created similarly. Could you explain/post an example?

Comment: You would need to allocate memory for your pointers, or alternatively point them to a local object on the stack (as one answer proposes). Normally you would do something like `outsideADT_T* ptr = malloc(sizeof(outsideADT_T));`. Then you just pass the pointer directly as `ptr`, not `&ptr` as this takes the address of a pointer (you don't need this in your case).

Comment: Remember pointers are just addresses in memory (or NULL). Creating a pointer does not create the object it's meant to point to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call `SomeFunction` with a pointer to a pointer to an `outsideADT_T` structure (double reference), whereas `SomeFunction` is declare to just take a pointer to that structure (single reference). Try this:

```
outsideADT_T outsidePTR; // <-- notice the lack of '*'
SomeFunction(&outsidePTR);
```

Furthermore, you dereference `insidePTR1` without initializing it. You'll need to allocate some memory for it at the beginning of `SomeFunction`:

```
outsidePTR->insidePTR1 = malloc(sizeof(insideADT1_T));
```

Same goes for `insidePTR2`.

Comment: Okay that makes some sense. So, even though the insideADTs have pre-defined sizes (ie one integer and one integer array with 500 elements) I still need a malloc call?

Comment: Yes, because the `outsideADT_T` structure declares its inside objects as pointers, and C doesn't allocate pointers for you.

Comment: @TheDude you would need a `malloc` call if you plan on carrying it outside of the scope where it is used. Or alternatively declare it globally so it persists for the entirety of the program.

Comment: Okay. I would rather allocate memory for it outside of SomeFunction, because it is going to be called a lot. Can I do this using:
    outsidePTR->insidePTR1 = malloc(sizeof(insideADT1_T));

Outside of the function?

Comment: It will likely be used out of scope. There are routines on the same level as SomeFunction that will need outsideADT. Also, SomeFunction has subroutines that will need outsideADT.

Comment: Yes, you can allocate it anywhere.

Comment: So then when I don't need it anymore, I will need to deallocate and delete the pointer. So I need to deallocate and delete the inside pointers first, then the outside, or can I just delete the outside and the inside gets taken care of too?

Comment: You will need to delete the inside pointers first, since deallocation is not recursive.

Comment: Okay. This is what I needed, I would say. Thank you for the quick and interactive replies!